# Store Tornado ( Python ) session in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, session, tornado

I am new to Python and MongoDB environment. I am implementing a small application in Python with Tornado + MongoDB. I want to store sessions in mongoDB.

In `server.py`

```
import os
import tornado.web 
import tornado.ioloop
import settings

application = tornado.web.Application(
  settings.urls,
  my_template_path,
  my_static_path
)
if __nam__ == '__main__':
  application.listen(8000)
  tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

In `settings.py`

```
import handler as H

urls = [
  (r"/",          H.ShowHome),
  (r"/login",     H.ShowLogin),
  (r"/dashboard", H.ShowDashboard)
]
```

In `handler.py`

```
import os
# import session or some library ????

class ShowHome(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  SESSION = False
  def initialize(self):
     #
     # check session related things here 
     #
     # self.SESSION = True or False based on session cookie 

  def get(self):
    if not self.SESSION:
       self.redirect('/login')
    else:
       self.render('index.html')

class ShowLogin(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  SESSION = False
  def initialize(self):
     #
     # check session related things here 
     #
     # self.SESSION = True or False based on session cookie 

  def get(self):
    if self.SESSION:
       self.redirect('/dashboard')
    else:
       self.render('login.html')


class ShowDashboard(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  SESSION = False
  def initialize(self):
     #
     # check session related things here 
     #
     # self.session = True or False based on session cookie 

  def get(self):
    if not SESSION:
       self.redirect('/login')
    else:
       self.render('dashboard.html')
```

In handlers I want to check session, how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
class Base(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get_unique_id(self):
        return self.get_secure_cookie('unique_id')

    def set_unique_id(self, some_value):
        return self.set_secure_cookie('unique_id', some_value)


class ShowLogin(Base):
  def get(self):
    if get_unique_id():
       # Get stuff from Mongo using unique_id
       # mongo calls
       self.redirect('/dashboard')
    else:
       self.render('login.html')


class LoginLogin(Base):
  def post(self):
    self.set_unique_id(some_id)
```

You probably dont want to do this though - Let Tornado handle if someone is logged in or out with the [authenticated decorator](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch2.0/web.html?highlight=authenticated#tornado.web.authenticated)

And unless you are holding a lot of data or very sensitive data it's normal (and easier) to put session data in the cookies

Comment: Thanks @andy, If I were to use Tornados' built-in session handler, how do I customize the session expiry and data format? I will be storing a JSON string  in session data, which contains information about user and some cached information like history and search query.

Comment: add expires_days to set_secure_cookie call:
http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch2.0/_modules/tornado/web.html#RequestHandler.set_secure_cookie